# Aligning the third word with 20 spaces from the beginning of the second word

Tags: linux, awk, sed, text-formatting, printf

We have the following file:

```
cat info.txt

linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Speed: 1000Mb/s

linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Duplex: Full
linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Duplex: Full
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Duplex: Full
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Duplex: Full

linux04.sys98.com net3f2    Link detected: no
linux04.sys98.com net3f3    Link detected: no

linux04.sys98.com net3f2    Speed: Unknown!
linux04.sys98.com net3f3    Speed: Unknown!

linux04.sys98.com net3f2    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
linux04.sys98.com net3f3    Duplex: Unknown! (255)

linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Link detected: yes
linux03.sys98.com net16777728       Link detected: yes
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Link detected: yes
linux01.sys98.com net3f0    Link detected: yes
```

We want to align the third word with 20 spaces from the beginning of the second word as the following expected results:

```
linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Speed: 1000Mb/s
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Speed: 1000Mb/s

linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Duplex: Full
linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Duplex: Full
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Duplex: Full
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Duplex: Full

linux04.sys98.com net3f2               Link detected: no
linux04.sys98.com net3f3               Link detected: no

linux04.sys98.com net3f2               Speed: Unknown!
linux04.sys98.com net3f3               Speed: Unknown!

linux04.sys98.com net3f2               Duplex: Unknown! (255)
linux04.sys98.com net3f3               Duplex: Unknown! (255)

linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Link detected: yes
linux03.sys98.com net16777728          Link detected: yes
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Link detected: yes
linux01.sys98.com net3f0               Link detected: yes
```

How to perform that with printf or any other solution?

Comment: Are the two columns in the original file tab-delimited?

Comment: no TAB delimited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'printf "%s %-20s %s\n", /(\S+\s+)(\S+)\s*(.*)/' your-file
```

Or to avoid touching lines that don't match that pattern:

```
perl -pe '$_ = sprintf "%s %-20s %s\n", $1, $2, $3
            if /(\S+\s+)(\S+)\s*(.*)/' your-file
```

Comment: was about to post a similar solution: `perl -pe 's/(\H+\h+\H+)\h+/sprintf "%-39s", $1/e'` .. only difference being mine would leave empty lines as is..

Comment: another question please what in case we need to print dot "." between the second word to the third word then can you give example for that ?

Comment: @jango, you can just add the `.` in the `printf` format (`%s %-20s . %s`).

Comment: @Sundeep, good point about lines that don't match the pattern. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`, you would add lots of spaces after the second field and then remove everything after the 20th char:

```
sed -E 's/([^ ]* ){2}/&                   /;s/( .{20}) */\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you would write

```
while read a b rest; do
    printf "%s %-20s %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$rest"
done < info.txt
```